# Javascript, Pressing one arrow key at time when moving

Tags: javascript, html, css, native, move

Looking to repair my little problem. This code is currently work well for moving any elements but
I want to find a way to remove pressing Up+Left|Down+Right to make it move diagonal

```js
            function keyboardController(keys, repeat){
                var timers = {};
                document.onkeydown = function(event){
                    var key = (event || window.event).keyCode;
                    if(!(key in keys))
                        return true;
                    if(!(key in timers)){
                        timers[key] = null;
                        keys[key]();
                        if(repeat !== 0)
                            timers[key] = setInterval(keys[key], repeat);
                    }
                    return false;
                };
                    
                document.onkeyup = function(event){
                    var key = (event || window.event).keyCode;
                    if(key in timers){
                        if(timers[key] !== null)
                            clearInterval(timers[key]);
                        delete timers[key];
                    }       
                };
            }
```

Comment: that code it is possible for you to be going left and right at the same time.....

Comment: So what you’re saying is that you don’t want it to be possible for things to move diagonal?

Comment: Exactly, i just want him to go left and right, top and down smootly, without diagonal, once you press 2 keys, just one have to be executed before the other.

Comment: So kill of any Interval running

Comment: Yeah but if i kill the interval, the element take a litle delay to start moving